# AWS Beanstalk / load balancer doesnt distribute load

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, scaling, elastic-beanstalk

I have two instances of EC2 running with Tomcat servers. I deployed my war using beanstalk. My load balancer has both the EC2 machines listed under the Instances tab.

I'm trying to do some load testing. When I generate the load and hit using the load balancer URL, requests are sent only to a single instance(not the same one during all runs). The other instance is completely idle.

Even in my beanstalk autoscaling settings, I've set the max and min instance count to 2 which ensures that both the machines are up all the time.

Could someone suggest what might be issue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have session stickiness turned on?

Comment: I dont maintain any session and the Sticky session option is also turned off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elastic load balancers spread the load by giving different IP addresses to different clients. How many machines do you have generating the load? If it's only one, then the load is only ever going to go to one machine at a time.

Comment: I think you got it. I tried reading a bit about load generation. Seems like, I need to setup a master-slave config of machines running JMeter to generate the load. Are there any other ways to achieve this? Please share if you have any ideas/suggestions/links/tutorials..Thanks.